How to update Amazon Corretto 8 with new build on Windows
Basically same question as here, except that I'm on Windows Server 2016.
The question is: is there any way to enable automatic check for updates and prompt the user for installation?
(I see no other way than manually checking for updates, downloading the new installer, uninstalling the previous version, installing the new one.)
